# VSCode: How to perform a "Quick Open -> Horizontal Split"?

Tags: visual-studio-code

On MacOS, I would like to perform a quick open (`⌘+p`) into a split **horizontal view**.

I have found zero documentation regarding how this can be done.

The only solution that I've found so far is performing a quick open (`⌘+p`) into a split **vertical view** (`ctrl+enter`).

Comment: See the `Open Side by Side Direction` setting to change all splits to horizontal.